# Protosem package in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols, packages, math-operators

In the list of the symbols there is a table n. 412: `protosem` Proto-Semitic Characters. Is it possibile to use these characters in math-mode?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{protosem}
\begin{document}
\textproto{\Aayin}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there is a tentative:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{protosem}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\disgiunt}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\Avav}}
    \begin{document}
    \textproto{\Avav} it is only in text mode. But in math-mode you can have $C\disgiunt D$
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do give `$\textproto{\Aayin}$` a try. :-)

Comment: @Mico Hi. You're right :-( I'm scarse. There is a reason for this question: I was trying to use `rotatebox` on `\Avev` command (if I remember well) to give an answer on this link:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554944/looking-for-a-disjoint-symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `\text` in order that the symbol changes size in subscripts or superscripts and `\textproto{Avav}`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{protosem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\disjoint}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\textproto{\Avav}}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$C\disjoint D_{C\disjoint D}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, rotate `\multimap` from `amssymb`.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\disjoint}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\multimap$}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$C\disjoint D_{C\disjoint D}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that `\text` will inherit the formatting of the surrounding text. This might be what you want—for example, if you’re formatting a title with bold text and math—but if not, there’s `\textnormal`.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I have rotated \multimap when I have given my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554944/looking-for-a-disjoint-symbol